# Google Admob ads not showing and test ads working fine

Tags: android, ios, flutter, admob, ads

I created an android app and I wanted to integrate ads from my google AdMob account but the Ads do not show up.

this type error showing.

= >> BannerAd event is MobileAdEvent.failedToLoad

= >> PlatformException(load_failed_ad, cannot reload a failed ad, id=821450265, null, null)

testing ads showing fine.

Comment: In my experience, sometimes it happens. It depends on how many ads can be displayed per day on your IP, on your area, etc...

Comment: Some more details would be useful here, for example the code that integrates AdMob and the error's stacktrace. Could you add them please?